# After installing graphql-tools and graphql-express. Error message in console 'Cannot find name 'AsyncIterator'

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql, async-iterator

**Error Log On initiating application**

While initiating the application it shows the following error and i tried couple of fixes from online which has mentioned below but none of them has worked requesting for suggestions and solutions

```
node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts(17,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterator'.
node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts(29,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterable'.
node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/stitching/makeRemoteExecutableSchema.d.ts(3,109): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterator'.
```

**Fixes Tried as per google results**

1. Adding `esnext.asynciterable` to the `tsconfig.json`
2. Adding `esnext` to the `tsconfig.json`

But none of them has worked. 
**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-graphql": "^0.6.12",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "graphql-tools": "^3.1.1",
    "ldapjs": "^1.0.1",
    "method-override": "^2.3.10",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.6",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.0",
    "nodemiral": "^1.1.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "request": "^2.85.0",
    "sendmail": "^1.2.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.4.5",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.4",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/async": "^2.0.47",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.16.8",
    "@types/chai": "^4.0.8",
    "@types/chai-http": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.3",
    "@types/errorhandler": "0.0.32",
    "@types/ldapjs": "^1.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.106",
    "@types/method-override": "0.0.31",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.44",
    "@types/mongodb": "^2.2.16",
    "@types/mongoose": "^4.7.28",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.7.35",
    "@types/mysql": "^2.15.3",
    "@types/node-schedule": "^1.2.2",
    "@types/request": "^2.47.0",
    "@types/serve-favicon": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/socket.io": "^1.4.32",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-http": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^2.3.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.13.3",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.3.0",
    "grunt-nodemon": "^0.4.2",
    "grunt-ts": "^6.0.0-beta.17",
    "grunt-tslint": "^5.0.1",
    "grunt-typedoc": "^0.2.4",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "mocha-typescript": "^1.1.12",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.4",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  }
```

Comment: Can you try to upgrade TypeScript? I am using 2.9.1 and it works for me. If that doesn't help, it would be great if would probably help the next responder if you could post your tsconfig.json file here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete node modules then:-

```
npm install 
npm install --save graphql-subscriptions
npm install --save @types/graphql
npm install --save @types/ws
```

add the following in tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "lib": [
     "esnext.asynciterable"
   ]
```

Comment: Hello Shivendra Gupta, I had installed the packages but it still returns the same error.

Comment: Delete node modules and then do ->  npm install

Comment: have u added "compilerOptions": {
  "lib": [
     "esnext.asynciterable"
   ]  in tsconfig.json ?

Comment: Hey Shivendra Gupta,  I tried the mentioned steps now i am getting the following errors

Comment: node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts(36,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterator'.

Comment: node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts(47,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterator'.

Comment: node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts(75,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterable'.

Comment: node_modules/apollo-link/node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts(17,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterator'.
node_modules/apollo-link/node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts(29,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterable'.
node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/stitching/makeRemoteExecutableSchema.d.ts(3,109): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterator'.

Comment: can you share your repository ?

Comment: Hello Shivendra, Actually its an internal project and under NDA. So i cannot share it outside. I am really sorry. But expecting your support

Comment: Shivendra i had fixed this issue. the root cause was due to incompaitablity of the pakages with the project version.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and adding

```
"lib": ["es2017", "esnext", "esnext.asynciterable"]
```

to my *tsconfig.json* did not help, which was frustrating.

I went through lots of suggestions and **eventually the answer by Shivendra solved it for me**. Hope this will help others coming here in the future.